# Preserve error messages from validation in rails while redirecting to a new view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am checking for errors using validates in my modal. Thats working fine and the error messages are shown(I used debugger to confirm this). Now comes the tricky part for me.

So now when the validation is failed I am doing this in my code:

```
  def create
    checked_segment_topics = params[:checked_segment_topics].split(",")
    @menu = Menu.create_menu(checked_segment_topics, menuparams)
    if @menu ==  true
      redirect_to menus_path
    else
      redirect_to newmenu_path
    end
  end
```

Because I am doing a redirect to a new view, the error messages are not shown. I tried render and the problem is it appends a UUID to the form's id. Because of this my javascript code fails. I have to find the forms ID to do a few calculations before the form is submitted.

Relevant parts of my routes.rb file is here:

```
get    '/menus'               => 'menus#index'
get    '/newmenu'             => 'menus#new'
resources :menus,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168017/how-do-i-store-an-instance-variable-across-multiple-actions-in-a-controller ?

Comment: I don't want to put it in a session variable or use @@ variables.

Comment: Then another way I think of is to do `save(validate: false)` in first controller, and then load it in second controller and run validations using `valid?`.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by first and second controller? I have just cone controller for this, and tis menu.

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables don't persist across the requests. So if you don't want to use session for this too, then other way I can think of is to store them in database without running validations.

```
def create
  # some logic to build @menu

  @menu.save(validate: false)

  # some logic for redirection
end
```

And then, fetch them in required action and run validations on it.

```
def new
  # some logic to fecth @menu

  @menu.valid?

  # some logic to render @menu
end
```

Comment: I used flash for showing the error messages which worked great. Thanks for helping me out anyway.

Comment: Great. BTW, flash uses session to store its data.