# How to preserve array of objects throughout several pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following situation in my rails project

application.html.erb:

```
...
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/sidebar' %>
<%= yield %>
...
```

_sidebar.html.erb:

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
  <li><%= link_to group.name, "#" %></li>
<% end %>
```

Sidebar consists of a list of groups which doesn't change often. That's why i don't want to query the list in DB every time I go to another page in content part (yield). Is there a way how can i preserve the list throughout several pages? I KNOW about the sessions and caches, but maybe there is a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: just noticed, you can keep it static then. if its not growing sidebar ! Some case you can go for redis :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I store an instance variable across multiple actions in a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168017/how-do-i-store-an-instance-variable-across-multiple-actions-in-a-controller)

Comment: @AtulKhanduri I'm not interested about saving it on backend. I wrote about frontend.

Comment: Okay. So, I guess, you can store the groups in a constant file and use that constant variable in the sidebar.

Comment: The groups are not constant.. user can add or remove groups, but it doesnt happen often.

Comment: There's no way to "preserve" those groups between requests. The page you're going into has to be built, so, data needs to be loaded again. You can use cache as you said, or you could build a javascript based webpage perhaps using Angular or any other JS framework out there, and just query and rebuild the part of the page you want without changing the rest of it.

Comment: You could use ajax, rendering just the `yield` part, not the whole _application.html.erb_.